# No external network access on Beaglebone

Tags: debian, ssh, networking

I have been trying to connect to the internet over WiFi on my Pocketbeagle. In trying, I have connected and have internet, but I cannot SSH into it on the same network, nor can I access a SimpleHTTPServer running on the Pocketbeagle. I have tried replacing Connman with Network-Manager, flushing my ip-tables rules, and reconfiguring many of the DNS services.

My Pocketbeagle is using the latest Debian IoT image, and I am trying the Ubuntu IOT image now. I have tried everything that I can think of, and don't know what to do next. I have been operating fully over serial, and do have full access to the internet and APT.

Comment: [My question (about an hour ago) may contain an answer to your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/600099/connmanctl-on-a-debian-pocketbeagle). I've figured out a few things, but the "beagles" have apparently abandoned ship - some of their material on github hasn't been updated in 3 years!

Comment: I have tried to solve this by adding routes, but I can only get as far as the interface between the pocketbeagle and my linux laptop. I don't yet understand why I cannot make the last step. Have you made any progress? [Interested in discussing this in chat?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat)