# connmanctl on a Debian 'pocketbeagle'

Tags: debian, ubuntu, embedded, connection-sharing, connman

I'm trying to configure my new [*"pocketbeagle"*](http://beagleboard.org/pocket) to share a network connection with my Ubuntu (20.04) laptop. PocketBeagle runs a version of Debian: 10.3/2020-04-06 ([REF](http://beagleboard.org/latest-images)).

*"pocketbeagle"* has neither WiFi nor Ethernet - only a single USB port. It supports `ssh`, and I can access the board this way through either or both of two IPs. Perhaps easier if I show it like this:

#### `ifconfig` run on *"pocketbeagle"* reveals:

```
$ ifconfig
usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.7.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.7.255
        inet6 fe80::6264:5ff:fefa:813a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 60:64:05:fa:81:3a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        ...
usb1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.6.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.6.255
        inet6 fe80::6264:5ff:fefa:813e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 60:64:05:fa:81:3e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        ...
```

#### `ifconfig` run on *"ubuntu"* reveals:

```
$ ifconfig 
enx606405fa813b: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.7.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.7.255
        inet6 fe80::2267:92a0:a191:297d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 60:64:05:fa:81:3b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        ...

enx606405fa813d: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.6.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.6.255
        inet6 fe80::3898:bc86:d0c2:cb53  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 60:64:05:fa:81:3d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        ...
```

#### Through a bit of research, I formulated a procedure to effect sharing as shown below:

1. Using the *"ubuntu"* GUI, I changed the *"Ethernet Connection"* w/ MAC `60:64:05:FA:81:3D` from its default *"automatic DHCP"* to a *"shared connection"*.
2. This changed its IP address from `192.168.6.1` assigned by *"pocketbeagle"* to `10.42.0.1`.

After making this change, here's what the *"ubuntu"* reports on its CLI:

```
$ ifconfig
enx606405fa813d: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.42.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.42.0.255
        inet6 fe80::3898:bc86:d0c2:cb53  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 60:64:05:fa:81:3d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        ...
```

3. At this point, the interfaces on *"pocketbeagle"* are unchanged, but obviously incorrect for connection sharing. I executed the following from the CLI on *"pocketbeagle"*

```
$ sudo connmanctl config usb1 --ipv4 manual 10.42.0.2 255.255.255.0 10.42.0.1 --nameservers 10.42.0.1
[sudo] password for debian: 
Error usb1: Method "SetProperty" with signature "sv" on interface "net.connman.Service" doesn't exist
```

Attempting a query of services w/ `connmanctl`:

```
$ sudo connmanctl 
Error getting VPN connections: The name net.connman.vpn was not provided by any .service files
connmancconnmanctl> services

connmanctl>
```

I'm not at all familiar with `connmanctl`, but my research suggested it was the only way to properly set up DNS service. Perhaps I screwed up? Perhaps there is something else I've missed? I then decided to try the configuration the "old way":

4. The following sequence of commands was used to re-configure the corresponding *"pocketbeagle"* interface in the "old way":

```
$ sudo ifconfig usb1 10.42.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
$ sudo route add default gw 10.42.0.1 usb1
$ sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
#
# add line: nameserver 10.42.0.1 
# save & exit editor
#
# yes - this is an awful kludge, but it did provide DNS
```

**And this worked!** - the *"pocketbeagle"* successfully connected to the Internet, DNS worked also.

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ ping unix.stackexchange.com
PING unix.stackexchange.com (151.101.1.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=9.01 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=11.8 ms
...
```

#### QUESTION: Obviously the issue is with my use of `connmanctl`, and not with *"pocketbeagle"* itself. What did I do incorrectly - why will `connmanctl` not work as intended?

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar issue with my Pocketbeagle. The default configuration consists of dnsmasq, which is acting as a local dns server. Whenever you connect by default, it does not have any access to the internet, and serves it's own DNS to allow access to the default Cloud9 IDE.

**My temporary fix is to run:** 
`sudo dhclient -r <usb0 or usb1>`.

This should pick up and temporarily configure DNS automatically from the host PC. You will have to re-run the command each time you restart the pocketbeagle. As far as I am aware, **connmanctl does not manage DNS on the Pocketbeagle** so setting the name-servers may not have any affect, neither with the bone-ubuntu image or the bone-debian.

To run the DNS resolver automatically, you need to install `systemd-resolved` and enable the service so that it starts on boot. This is generally the method I use to get internet access.

Comment: This is a useful answer, but I am still searching for an explanation as to my failure with `connmanctl`. I am watching [your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/600080/no-external-network-access-on-beaglebone) with interest as this is also something I need to do.

Comment: I have got the routing worked out. I can now reach *pocketbeagle* from any host on my LAN via its IP address, and likewise reach any host from *pocketbeagle* if I know its IP address. So DNS has moved to the top of my list :)  I tried `sudo dhclient -r usb1`. It seems to resolve an address, but for some reason I am not getting replies to my `ping` tests from anything on the other side of my fw/router. Working that issue now.